Trouble With Accessing SQLite database twice in the same Code:
There are two tables in my SQLite database, "SAI,db": a "tickers" table and a "filtered_stocks" table. When I access my "tickers" table within my code, the code works perfectly fine, but if I try and access "filtered_stocks" later on, in the same code, it gives me an error, saying "no such table: filtered_stocks".
I firstly verified whether "filtered_stocks" actually exists within SAI.db using dbListTables, and I can confirm that it is in the database. I also tried to split the database SAI.db, into a separate database housing the "tickers" table, and a separate database housing the "filtered_stocks" table, and establishing two separate connections within my code, to see if that makes a difference - it didn't.
